# sstableexpiredblockers: what to do having blocking SSTables in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have realized that some sstables are not dropped even if they contained only tombstones.
Using  a manual major compaction these sstables are removed.
Perhaps it needs to update unchecked_tombstone_compaction to true along with gc_grace_period

I have seen utility sstableexpiredblockers utility that will reveal blocking SSTables that prevent an SSTable from dropping.

> During compaction, Cassandra can drop entire SSTables if they contain
>   only expired tombstones and if it is guaranteed to not cover any data
>   in other SSTables. This diagnostic tool outputs all SSTables that are
>   blocking other SSTables from being dropped.

I do not understand:

> ... if it is guaranteed to not cover any data in other SSTables ...

Since my compaction strategy is TimeWindowCompactionStrategy, all sstables have different time intervals.

I would like to know how handle those blocking SSTables.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old now but noticed it wasn't answered. If you still have some info here could you show / share the output of sstablemetadata for tables that you think should be compacted away?

Comment: Hi markc, thank you for you interest !  I found out that timeseries were written with wrong timestamps. I expected the sstables to contain the data of the last week having set TTL = 1 week. However, there were tables referring to older timestamps. I found that there were clients with unsynched clock and their timestamps were older than one week. Eventually I had to reject these data.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at it(bit late). You may check if the NTP server pool was set up during installation. This can be a big reason of clock not getting synched.

Also, it has been seen that instead of relying on VM, it is a good idea to use a physical machine for this purpose.